# How to return a plain object rather than an array of object

Tags: php

I am getting a single record response with php script below

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include "db.php";

$uid = 1;

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE isAdmin = ?");

$stmt->execute([$uid]);

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode(
    [
    'status' =>'success',
    'message' => $result,
    ]);
```

I get a response of

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": [
        {
            "s_n": "1",
            "email": "seeme@mail.com",
            "info": "Good morning",
            "isAdmin": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want a response of

```
   {
        "status": "success",
        "message": 
            {
                "s_n": "1",
                "email": "seeme@mail.com",
                "info": "Good morning",
                "isAdmin": "1"
            }
    }
```

How can I get the object response, instead of the array object response?

Comment: Change `'message' => $result` to `'message' => array_shift($result)` and try again.

Comment: You can use `$result =  $stmt->fetch();` to get only single record and you will get in object instead of array.

Comment: On a side note, you are retrieving the whole database table only to use one arbitrary row (not even randomise it). Your SQL should define a deterministic order and limit to one result.

Comment: Please close duplicates instead of answering them via comment.